# How to kill a focused window in Xdotool, but keep some windows out?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, automation, kill

I have a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to kill a focused window with

```sh
xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill
```

I am on GNOME, X11 with lightdm, and when all windows have been killed and I press the shortcut gnome-session restarts, is there a way to keep some windows out?

I want to keep out:

- X11
- GNOME
- lightdm

windows

Answer (score 0):

### I found the solution:

`xdotool getwindowfocus windowclose`